# What is the easiest way to keep an offline copy of a webdav share?

Tags: sync, dropbox, webdav

I have a webdav share configured for my small group of users.  This is great for sharing files, like Dropbox.  But it lacks Dropbox's functionality of keeping the files locally when the computer is disconnected from the internet.

Certain users in my group require that these files be locally accessible (via a prior, automated sync) even when there is no internet access.

I'm looking for a solution to this (or multiple solutions) that will work on both Windows and Mac OSX.  Rsync looks good, but I've heard of issues with it being slow with webdav, it will be hard to configure for my OSX users, and unavailable to my users on Windows.

Is there an open-source tool, or some easily configured built-in tool, that can automate this process for these users?

Comment: Also consider using a distributed version control system, like Git or Mercurial.

Answer (score 2):

## WebDAV-Sync

Have you tried [WebDAV-Sync](http://www.re.be/webdav_sync/index.xhtml)?

It is open source.

There is a configuration file, and it syncs when you execute it.

---

## my-cloud-sync

[my-cloud-sync](https://github.com/Alfresco/my-cloud-sync) is a Dropbox clone developed by [Alfresco Inc.](http://alfresco.com).

Internally it uses [Sardine](https://github.com/lookfirst/sardine/), a WebDAV library, so as far as I understand it can sync with any WebDAV server.

Comment: Lftp can be used to mirror a WebDAV folder.

Comment: Is rclone an alternative here?

Comment: @nicolas-raoul the only reference I could find about the broken link of my-could-sync is that https://www.javatips.net/api/my-cloud-sync-master/jMyCloudClient/src/main/java/com/alfresco/jmycloudclient/AlfrescoSyncClient.java