# Windows 8.1 | Make remote network locations available offline

Tags: networking, sync, nas, windows-8.1-upgrade, offline-files

I've set up a NAS on my network, and would like to make some of the files accessible offline on my laptop.

I can do this by mapping a network drive to \\NASNAME\share, and then right-clicking to select "Always available offline". However, if I map the network drive to \\routername.someddnsprovider.com\share (which is shared by webdav), there is no option to make available offline. Why is this option missing, and what can I do to get the same functionality?

Effectively, I would like to have on-demand sync from my NAS from any internet connection (not just when connected to my router's intranet).

Comment: The share itself has to allow offline file caching.

Comment: So then it's simply because of the protocol being used? The share itself is the same; the only difference is whether I access it through SMB on the intranet or WebDAV via ddns.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/365905/dropbox-like-client-for-webdav

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/215038/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-keep-an-offline-copy-of-a-webdav-share

Comment: Basically yeah, WebDAV doesn't support offline files.

Comment: Thanks @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007! Intuitively it wasn't clear to me that offline files was dependent on protocol; it seems like something that could be implemented on the client side without any awareness on the server. Now that I know I can work out a solution.